# Configuring VirtualBox Ports on Mac OS 10.12 to work with Window 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to use realterm version 2.0.0.70 within a virtual machine I have on my Mac. I am trying to configure both USB ports that I have as serial ports so that my device can be registered by the virtual machine.

My main issue is that VirtualBox starts when I configure the path address trying to use a Host Pipe.

Below is an example of my configuration

[image]

I am not sure whether this is the correct configuration for trying to get the serial ports work with the Windows 7 Virtual Machine. Any advice on how to configure the usb to work as the serial port correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think this https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html might help you ? Seems your confirmation is good, what's "not" working ?